# query to count the table rows using execute immediate

Tags: plsql

Write a function named `get_total_records`, to pass the table name as a parameter, and get back the number of records that are contained in the table.

Please test your function with multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

Which database is it? If Oracle, here's one option:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_records (par_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     retval  NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  7        'select count(*) from ' || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (par_table_name)
  8        INTO retval;
  9
 10     RETURN retval;
 11  END;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT get_total_records ('emp') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
        14

SQL> SELECT get_total_records ('dept') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
         4

SQL> SELECT get_total_records ('does_not_exist') result FROM DUAL;
SELECT get_total_records ('does_not_exist') result FROM DUAL
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-44002: invalid object name
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 383
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.GET_TOTAL_RECORDS", line 6


SQL>
```